# select dropdown materialize css full width

Tags: css, materialize

I'm trying to add 2 select dropDown materialize css side by side, in my react app.
But instead they are stacked one on top of each-other and taking up the full width. here is my code.

```
const SearchPillows = () => {


    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="input-field col s12">
                <select>
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                </select>
                <div className="input-field col s12">
                    <select>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
                        <option value="1" className="left">Option 1</option>
                        <option value="2" className="left">Option 2</option>
                        <option value="3" className="left">Option 3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>hello</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SearchPillows;
```

Please assist, thanks !!

Comment: You are using `s12` (entire 12 column) instead of `s6` (instead of 6 for each).

Comment: I changed it. still does not work

Comment: Is it still taking 12 columns when you web inspect? Did you try with < 6 columns as well.

Comment: can you please provide more line of code?

Comment: In the inspector says "s6", but it still takes up the whole length within the container, and there stacked.  <6 does not do anything

Comment: @Sahil Khan Thats all the code there is for those inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several errors in your code:

**1) No `.row` div. `.col` must live in rows to be responsive.**

**2) No class name to make the columns side by side, which is `.s6`, `.m6` `.l6` etc.**

**3) Missing closing `div` tag after the first select.**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"><!-- < This was missing -->
              <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                <select>
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                </select>
              </div><!-- < This was missing -->
                <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
                    <select>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
                        <option value="1" className="left">Option 1</option>
                        <option value="2" className="left">Option 2</option>
                        <option value="3" className="left">Option 3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>hello</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/GRogBOz).

Comment: Cool. If it's the correct answer, please mark it so :D